# Add New Url in Django project

Tags: python, django

Hello Guys i got some problems about adding new url  So here is my app
url.py  :

```
  url(r'^question/$', views.question_mark , name = 'question-mark'),
```

here is my views.py :

```
def question_mark(request): 
    template = 'blog/question.html'
    return render(request,template)
```

and here is myroject  url.py :

```
 url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
```

but  while i am typing   www......com/en/blog/question     i am getting  page not found error  what i am din wrong ?

Comment: why do you have /en/ in your url?

Comment: Where does the `/en/` comes from?

Comment: it automatically chooses  en/ by itself , even if i only type /blog/question it will automatically change it to en/blog/question

Comment: Did you add the app_name = 'blog' above your urls